# How to span the range in random function Python?

Tags: python, random

I want to get a random number from 0 to 1e-20, I'm using the following function in Python

```
random.uniform(1e0, 1e-20)
```

However, the numbers are only from 1e0 missing the rest of the range such as 1e-12, 1e-9, etc.

How can I get a number among all the range?

Update:

```
0.8997498299014705
0.8320065922653802
0.9894039561126263
0.015205024292817781
0.8460417648041141
0.9744256248957714
0.10799180387896301
0.195940099219041
0.19830039605178706
0.694803475206833
0.5869371229317706
0.5762011063374192
0.2761909685255569
0.9757648088382384
0.0786057337977103
0.7090714156637489
0.6946835664286121
0.5975036696040513
0.7426259364954565
0.1116434886497456
0.6691228131282176
```

Comment: This works as expected, returning numbers between 1e-20 and 1. What different output did you expect? Note that the probability of the output being smaller than 1e-12 is close to  1e-12, so don't expect to see outputs of that magnitude too often...

Comment: I've updated the post with some outputs. You can observe how the values are closer to 1e0 than 1e-20, I expected a variety of values "decimal position variation"

Comment: Then you don't want an uniform distribution. In this case, you should clarify exactly which distribution you want to obtain.

Comment: I want a random distribution, I've tried rand but it doesn't work with float

Comment: There's an infinity of different possible random distributions (see for example some very common ones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions)). You clearly don't want an uniform one, but we can't guess how you would want your random numbers to be distributed if you don't explain that.

Comment: I don't need a specific random distribution but one that covers all the range with the same probability

Comment: This is exactly what the uniform distribution is, and that is exactly why you get so few very small values, as the probability to get them in an uniform distribution is, of course, very low. So, as already explained, you clearly don't want an uniform distribution, and what you mean by `cover all the range with the same probability` is not what 'same probability` means in probabilities. So, please explain what you mean exactly.

Comment: I mean that at each iteration, I can get 1e-8, 1e-2, e-11, e-17, e-5, e-14, etc.

Comment: @Poyitadetroya note that `uniform` (or any code for that matter) can't distinguish between you entering `(1e0, 1e-20)` and `(1, 0.00000000000000000001)`, it just sees the values of the floating point parameters and generates values between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, your code does what you claim you want, but your wants seem to be different then what you claim.

It seems that what you want is to generate random numbers such that their base 10 logarithms are uniformly distributed between -20 and 0. Such numbers are called [log-uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_distribution) rather than uniform. If so -- just generate the exponents uniformly in [-20,0] and then raise 10 to these numbers:

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    print(pow(10,random.uniform(-20,0)))

#typical output:

0.0005139787035284368
1.1615946347073329e-14
2.455360025929292e-07
1.615010435306129e-14
0.007962057074320813
1.1641947007189282e-17
3.725480259325438e-18
3.5028054406435525e-09
1.4739445873699184e-11
2.322173584509162e-16
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the [numpy docs for uniform](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) the formula for the probability is p(x)=1/(b-a) within the interval [a=1e0,b=1-20e]. This means that the probability will always be -1, because b is so close to zero that it's like dividing 1 by -1. If you swap and and b it becomes +1. And somehow this results in an output only between 1 and 0.

Testing with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

test = np.random.uniform(1e0, 1e-20, 500)

plt.hist(test, bins=50, density=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: how can I solve my issue?